# Make UPS-like cache searchable in winter

Tags: geocaching

When hiding something in the forest on the surface, there's a great practice called UPS (Unusual Pile of Sticks, the German version is very sweet: Hasengrill). They prevent people from boaring a few acres of land and are great replacement for spoiler photos. However, snow makes them invisible.

How should I build my UPS to make it visible even in winter? Well, for 2-meter thick snow nothing would help, but it's usual, at least in Central Europe, that snow has 10-20 cm.

Answer (score 3):

I once saw a cache that got around this problem nicely by implanting 4 relatively tall upright sticks around the other pile of sticks. I think this only worked because it was relatively off the beaten track, so others weren't likely to stumble across them and tear them down or mess around with them - but it certainly acted as a good visual clue.

When I found this cache it was actually in the height of summer, though I imagine it would work equally well, if not better, for highlighting a cache in snow that wasn't too thick.